# Reconciling vertex modification conflicts in Geodatabase Versioning?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

Is it possible to edit the same feature in ArcSDE in two different versions

... and reconcile/post version A's edits to the parent,

... and then reconcile/post version B's edits of same feature,

... and then see which vertex modification conflicts arise,

... and keep all vertex modifications that do not conflict?

Answer (score 4):

My understanding of the process would say no.
When you rec and post you get entity level conflict resolution (not vertex or attribute level).